# How to set a value that was returned as an 'object'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have one example and it works. But, when I try to set one 'object' value to return with the text, it does not work ...
The response and request (console Chrome): 
The response: `{"error":{"error":{"context":["Context must be of type \"object\` .

This **example** returns right inside the API:

```
function etc(input, response) {
  var responseText = null;
  if (!response.output) {
    response.output = {};
  } else {
    return response;
  }
  if (response.xs && response.xs[0]) {
    var x = response.xs[0];

    if (x.confidence >= 0.75) {
      responseText = 'etc etc etc ' + x.x;
    } else if (x.confidence >= 0.5) {
      responseText = 'etc etc etc' + x.x;
    } else {
      responseText = 'etc etc etc';
    }
  }
  response.output.text = responseText;
  return response;
}
```

My code:

```
 success:function(output, input, response) {
          console.log(output);
         // alert(output.request.number); THIS RETURN THE VALUE BUT I NEED --->
       var responseText = null;
       var outputTest = {};
       outputTest = output.request.number; // THE VALUE I WANT RETURN


       responseText = ("The value is: "+ outputTest);
```

Image return (console Chrome):

[image]

**The API understanding:**

[image]

**I try it and works but dont show in my API**:

```
success:function(output, input, response) {
      console.log(output);
     // alert(output.request.number); THIS THE VALUE I NEED
  var responseText = null;
  var outputTeste = {};
  outputTeste = output.request.number;
  var latestResponse = Api.getResponsePayload();

  var context = latestResponse.context;
  responseText = ("The value is:", + outputTeste);
```

**And this return in console (Chrome):**
[image]

Comment: If it is a simple object with no circular dependencies: JSON.stringify(object) will produce a string-serialized version of this object.

Comment: Where do I put it?

Comment: responseText = ("The value is: "+ JSON.stringify(outputTest));

Comment: Can you provide the console o/p for request ?

Comment: Hi, I add the image with --> console.log(output);

Comment: You can't make an object to text. you can do it like responseText = ("The value is: "+ outputTest.text);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works:

```
success:function(output, input, response) {
      console.log(output);
     // alert(output.request.number); THIS THE VALUE I NEED
  var responseText = null;
  var outputTest = {};
  outputTest = output.request.number;
  var latestResponse = Api.getResponsePayload();
  responseText = 'The value is: ' + outputTest);
```